# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Boa Noite Pessoal,
estou tentando criar uma tabela com duas chaves estrangeira, porém fica dando o erro de Cannot add foreign key constraint, não entendo por que, segue abaixo a instrução SQL.

segue a tabela Matricula

```
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| aluno_codMatricula | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| turma_codTurma     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

segue a instrução da criação da tabela com as foreign keys

```
CREATE TABLE Chamada(codChamada INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, data DATE NOT NULL, presente BOOL NOT NULL, matricula_aluno_codMatricula INT NOT NULL, matricula_turma_codTurma INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(codChamada), FOREIGN KEY (matricula_aluno_codMatricula) REFERENCES Matricula(aluno_codMatricula), FOREIGN KEY (matricula_turma_codTurma) REFERENCES Matricula(turma_codTurma)) Engine=Innodb;
```

porém ocorre o erro: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Pelo que você postou a chave primária da tabela Matrícula é uma chave composta (aluno_codMatricula, turma_codTurma) e não apenas o campo aluno_codMatricula. A chave primária da tabela Matricula não deveria ser apenas aluno_codMatricula? Ou a matrícula do aluno pode variar de turma para turma em seu modelo de dados?

Comment: @anonimo acho q leu errado, é um campo só cada chave, não é composta, a primeira `matricula_aluno_codMatricula` e a segunda `matricula_turma_codTurma`, mas é estranho duas foreign keys para a mesma tabela, será que isso está certo?

Comment: Os dois campos contém PRI na coluna Key. Se não for uma chave composta então o software que você utilizou para exibir é totalmente contraintuitivo.

Comment: é uma tabela gerada quando se tem relação N para N, preciso saber na chamada quem é o aluno pelo código da matricula e qual turma ele pertence.